# Scheduling background job independent of ISS scope

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, taskscheduler

I have my business logic and the operation i want schedule in Business dll.
I want to schedule my scheduling operation which is in my business dll.
How can i create a separate background job independent of ISS scope and can also be triggered from the web application using a HTTP(s) request.

So far i have seen people create scheduling task within the application which means  it is in IIS's scope.

But i want to run it as a windows service.

Comment: If you want a Windows service, then create a Windows service.  If you have full control over the server then this can be installed in addition to IIS.  If you don't, then you'll need a different server to run your service.

Comment: You want to change the ISS of a job from the current user if it is going to be independent.  It sound like you want to create a service that a user can submit a job to be run as a background job.  So it seems like you just need to create a service and then set the "run as admin" so it takes user submitted jobs and submit jobs as background tasks.  Make sure you do not run the submitted jobs with "run as admin" permission.

Comment: Use .NET Core 3.0 which starts to give you built-in support for Windows service hosting, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/net-core-workers-as-windows-services/ Those who chose to be in IIS scope (via Hangfire or other options) are commonly facing issues.

Comment: @Neil if i create windows service separately, do i need to add my business dll to that windows service ?

Comment: Yes it will become part of the deployment.

Comment: @Neil but what i want to achieve is have a separate service that does the scheduling task but i should be able to trigger it manually using a HTTP request from my web app and rest it be should be alive and keep on running when my webapp is not active.

Comment: @jdweng yes that's what i am trying to achieve can you provide some source where it is done ?

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer or this : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bae1d2ba-8f13-4178-a3a7-2e7c27e8c335/how-to-schedule-a-windows-service-to-run-at-4pm-every-day?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: If your 'scheduler' is just a way of running tasks when required, then just POST from the Windows service to the Web service.  You could use something like Quartz to handle keeping track and firing the tasks.

Comment: @jdweng yeah that's kind of what i am looking for thanks for the help. but i wanted to know if it is possible to invoke a windows service from web app ? like my service runs at a specific time but is it possible to trigger it using HTTP request  when ever i want ?

Comment: @Neil yes but it will be in scope of IIS.

Comment: yes it will be.  Why is that a problem?  IIS will just 'wake up' the web site when called.   The other alternative is have the Windows service consume a queue, which the web site can push items onto when you want to call it manually.

Comment: that's a problem because IIS can consume only 50% of system resource and it will effect the performance the if i run the task on ISS and other users are accessing the website at same time and the scheduling job is going be CPU and memory extensive.

Comment: And yes you are right about the queue system someone suggested me that also but didn't know how to do it. can you provide some link or resource about it @Neil

Comment: Rabbit ( https://www.rabbitmq.com/ ), AWS (https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/ ) or Azure ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted)  are the 3 I've used recently.

Comment: thanks for the helps Neil and jdweng.

Answer (score 1):

Shameless plug: you can use [Runly](https://www.runly.io) to easily package up your job as a nuget package and then deploy it to a separate [Windows service on your machine](https://www.runly.io/docs/hosting/).

Runly also gives you things right out of the box like [fault tolerance](https://www.runly.io/docs/fault-tolerance/) and built-in [OSS components to show progress of your jobs](https://www.runly.io/docs/integration/js/) in your web app.

We built it for people like you who would like a simple and quick way to break logic out of their main application and run it out-of-process. I hope you find it useful.